# how to send data outside form while submitting -MVC ,HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In my view there is a form shown below

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRecords", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
                 { %>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button_62" title="Save" />
                 // some controls
                <%} %>
```

My need is that there is another form in the same view.While clicking save button i need to get value of a particular text box that is outside the form  submitting .I cant put that control in same form.And i cant use ajax request to send data. Is there anyway i can append data outside of the form before submitting it?

I want to get  value of that textbox(out sid the submitted form) in controller Saverecords ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer using javascript

using jQuery you could set a hidden field in the the form above containing the same value as the control that resides in the other form.

if you add an id to your form above then.

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
  $("#myhiddenId").val($("#fieldInOtherFormId").val());
});
```