# p:ajax, how to submit information from other forms?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4**. I have p:layout with `p:tree` in left layout unit, and the list of panels in the central unit. After selecting/unselecting the nodes on tree I'm rendering/unrendering the panels. The general structure looks like that:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" minSize="150" size="300">
<h:form id="tree"> 
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{tree.root}" var="node"
    selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{tree.selectedNodes}">  

    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{tree.treeSelect}" process=":main" update=":main:panels"/>
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{tree.treeUnselect}" process=":main" update=":main:panels"/>
    <p:treeNode>  
        <h:outputText value="#{node.title}" />  
    </p:treeNode>  

</p:tree>
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>


<p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Panels" styleClass="noscroll">
<h:form id="main"> 
<p:outputPanel id="panels" styleClass="center-panels">

<!-- here go the panels -->

</p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

But the panels contains the input fields. I've noticed, that the input fields are reseted after click on tree, so I've added the process `attribute`. I've tried with `:main`, `:main:panels`, `@all`, but none of them have functioned.

How can I work correctly with that scenario? PrimeFaces bugture (a bug that is feature) doesn't allow using single form when you are using `p:layout`, at least this is stated in documentation. And using multiple forms, I'm loosing data.

Comment: Did you try setting `:main` in update attribute as well?

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" header="Opciones" size="175">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:panelMenu style="width:200px">   
                        <p:submenu label="Clientes" >
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="# {templateMB.templateAddCliente}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Buscar"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Listado"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Editar"/>
                        </p:submenu> 
                        <p:submenu label="Contratos">  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar"  icon="ui-icon-close"/>  
                        </p:submenu>  
                        <p:separator/>  
                        <p:submenu label="Suplementos" >  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" icon="ui-icon-signal"/>  
                        </p:submenu>  
                    </p:panelMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:form id="form2">  
                    <ui:include src="#{templateMB.centerTemplate}" />  
                </h:form> 
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: OP question is about sending data from `<h:form id="form2">` in an ajax request started inside `<h:form id="form1">` (which is impossible using JSF components only by the way, but don't tell).

Comment: In Spanish: OP necesita enviar información del form2 en una petición que concierne a form1, lo cual no es posible con componentes JSF. En un request por submit, normalmente se envían los datos del formulario donde se encuentra el request, si quieres enviar datos adicionales debes agregarlos manualmente. Este problema no es específico de JSF, sino de desarrollo Web. Por ejemplo, acá hay un caso descrito en ASP.Net: [how to send data outside form while submitting -MVC ,HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5482189/1065197)

Comment: Here's a JSF explanation about similar problem: [submit multiple forms with p:commandbutton](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9738871/1065197), note that in this case OP's using a `<p:commandButton>` to start the request instead of `<p:ajax>`. Still, it doesn't matter how you start the request, you can only submit a single form. If you want to add additional data you should do it manually.